# Whats the best way to perform selective record replication at an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, replication

Suppose the following scenario:
I have a master database that contains lots of data, in this database I have a key table that I'm going to call DataOwners for this example, the DataOwners table has 4 records, each record of each of the other tables in the database "belongs" directly or indirectly to a record of the DataOwners, and by belongs I mean is linked to it with foreign keys. 
I also have other 2 slave databases with the exact same structure from my master database whose are only updated through replication from my master database, but SlaveDatabase1 should only have records from DataOwner 2 and SlaveDatabase2 should only have records from DataOwners 1 and 3 whereas MasterDatabase has records of DataOwners 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Is there any tool for Oracle that allows me to do this kind of selective record replication?
If not, is there any way to improve my replication method? which is:

- add to each table a trigger that inserts the record changes in a group of replication tables
- execute the commands of the replication tables at selected slaves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Golden Gate software can do all these tasks.  Insert/Update/Delete have the same order of the master db, so it can avoid the foreign keys and other constraint issues.

MasterDatabase Extract generates a trail file, then split out the data to DB 1,2,3 and 4.

It also can do multiple ways replications, i.e. DB 1 sends data back to the Master DB.

Besides the Golden Gate, trigger may be your other option.  But it requires some programming.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option would be to define materialized views in the various slave databases that replicate just the data that you want.  So, for example, if there is a table `A` in the master database, then in slave database 1, you'd create a materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW a
  <<refresh criteria>>
AS
SELECT a.*
  FROM a@to_master a,
       dataOwners@to_master dm
 WHERE a.dataOwnerID = dm.dataOwnerID
   AND dm.some_column = <<some criteria that selects DataOwner2>>
```

while slave database 2 has a very similar materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW a
  <<refresh criteria>>
AS
SELECT a.*
  FROM a@to_master a,
       dataOwners@to_master dm
 WHERE a.dataOwnerID = dm.dataOwnerID
   AND dm.some_column = <<some criteria that selects DataOwner1 & 3>>
```

Of course, if the `dataOwnerID` can be hard-coded, you could simplify things and avoid doing the join.  I'm guessing, though, that there is some column in the `DataOwners` table that identifies which slave a particular owner should be replicated to.

Assuming that you want only incremental changes to be replicated, you'd need to create some materialized view logs on the base tables in the master database.  And you would probably want to configure [refresh groups](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14226/repmview.htm#REPLN109) on the slave databases so that all the materialized views would refresh at the same time and would be transactionally consistent with each other.

Comment: +1  This is basically the answer I was going to write up, but you got there first :)

Comment: Yes Justin there is a Slaves table and a Slaves_DataOwners table the way you mentioned, too bad I can't use materialized views the way you said.

Comment: @Daniel - Why can't you use materialized views?  If there are additional constraints that you haven't mentioned, that would definitely be helpful to mention since that may also eliminate other approaches like Streams or GoldenGate.

Comment: Yes there are other constraints but since they are political constraints rather than technical ones they simply don't belong here (Damn management). I have decided to rework the existing trigger system, but thanks anyway.